# How can i convert this raw query to eloquent scope?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
SELECT *
FROM employment_informations t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM employment_informations  t2
   WHERE t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id 
   AND t1.field_name = t2.field_name
   AND t2.created_at > t1.created_at
)
```

This is what I have so far.

```
$builder->whereNotExists(function ($builder) {
        $builder->select(\DB::raw(1))
                ->from('employment_informations t2')
                ->whereRaw('employment_informations.employee_id = t2.employee_id
                    AND employment_informations.field_name = t2.field_name
                    AND t2.created_at > employment_informations.created_at
                ');
    });
```

I don't know how to alias table in eloquent scope.
here's the error:

```
[09:15:38] LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hris.employment_informations t2' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `employment_informations` where not exists (select 1 from `employment_informations t2` where employee_id = t2.employee_id
                    AND field_name = t2.field_name
                    AND t2.created_at > created_at)) {"userId":1,"exception":{"errorInfo":["42S02",1146,"Table 'hris.employment_informations t2' doesn't exist"]}}
```

doesn't work using `as` either:

```
->from('employment_informations as t2')
```

If possible I want to alias the table with t1 and the subquery table to t2, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: seems you missed `SELECT * FROM employment_informations t1` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports aliases on tables and columns with AS. Try

`$query = DB::table('tablename AS t')->select('t.id AS uid')->get();`

Comment: yes, i know i can use this on select,. but how about in global scope, how can I apply this in global scope?